# Javascript error message not showing in php

Tags: javascript, php

First time posting here so be kind!
For some reason when my php script reaches the 
if ($beds == 'nopref')
the only way I can get the message to display is with echo $message.
The following line with javascript won't display it like my other pages. 
Any ideas?
CODE:

```
<?php    
$beds = $_POST['beds'];
$orientation = $_POST['orientation'];
$checkin = $_POST['checkin'];
$checkout = $_POST['checkout'];
$conn = mysqli_connect("localhost", "user", "password", "name"); 
    if(!$conn) 
    { 
       die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error()); 
    } 
    if ($beds == 'nopref')
    {
        $message = "Please select how many beds you'd like";
        echo $message;
        echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('$message');</script>";
    }
 ?>
```

Comment: I'm no PHP expert, but try: 
`echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('" . $message. "');</script>";`
Also check your browser console for any errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have broken text because of ' in `you'd`. Try this:

```
$message = htmlspecialchars("Please select how many beds you'd like", ENT_QUOTES);
```

Comment: It was the ' in you'd. I just changed it to you would and the problem was solved. Thanks!

Comment: I know that was ' in you'd -  I told you that. That's why still you should be familiar with htmlspecialchars because it is very useful function.

Answer (score 1):

You can escape a ' in JavaScript like \'

```
 if ($beds == 'nopref')
    {
        $message = "Please select how many beds you\'d like";
        echo $message;
        echo '<script>alert("'.$message.'");</script>';
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
 print "<script type='text/javascript'>window.alert('$message');</script>";
```

or

```
print "<script type='text/javascript'>window.alert('Please select how many beds you had like');</script>";
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
<?php
   $message=htmlspecialchars("Hello World's",ENT_QUOTES);
   echo "<script>alert('$message')</script>";
?>
```